# Can I (how do I) disable "Friendly HTTP Error Messages" in MS Edge Browser?

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

As a web developer, I depend on the ability to disable "Show Friendly HTTP Error Messages" and enable "Display a Notification about Every Error". These are both in the Advanced Settings in IE.

I have to test an app in MS Edge, but I'm getting a 500 internal Server error. No big deal, I can fix it **if** I know what's wrong.

I don't see any such options in Advanced Settings in Edge.

Is it possible to turn off Friendly Error Messages in MS Edge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible right now but you can:

- use f12 tools to see the actual content of the page
- use Internet Explorer or another browser in which you can disable friendly errors to see the detail.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, it helps in that at least I know!  ;-)  Thanks!

Comment: Great ! could you mark my answer as good if you find that it is ? :)Thanks a lot

Comment: Wow, Microsoft is on the leading Edge of crappiness once again (see what I did there?). Why the heck is it so hard for them to have a toggle hidden somewhere?

Comment: No. The F12 tools does not show you the content of the error page from server. Instead, it does show the content of the Edge's builtin 500-error page.

Comment: ouch. that's brutal.