# How do I show asp.net error details in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: asp.net

How do I show asp.net error pages (Yellow screen of death) in Microsoft Edge?

More specifically, how do I disable friendly http error messages at browser level?
The OS I am trying this on is Windows Server 2016 Standard Technical Preview 5.

I have made sure to have `<customErrors mode="Off"/>` under system.web in the web.config

I can successfully use eventvwr to find ASP.NET errors including the stack trace in the eventlog so I know there are proper asp.net errors happening.

I can' see any relevant setting under Edge -> Advanced settings.

I need to disable friendly error message in Edge. Any ideas?

[image: Friendly error message]

In IE11 it used to be here

[image: Show friendly HTTP error messages]

**Update :** I'm voting to close my own question because it is a duplicate of this

[Can I (how do I) disable "Friendly HTTP Error Messages" in MS Edge Browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34190097/can-i-how-do-i-disable-friendly-http-error-messages-in-ms-edge-browser)

Comment: Microsoft Edge is an Internet browser. As far as I know you don't enable remote errors by going to your Internet browser settings. If so anyone worldwide could do it and that could be a security issue. You need to check you configuration file and IIS settings.

Comment: @derloopkat see my 2nd screenshot, there is indeed a setting to hide/show HTTP error messages (in IE 11 at least). And yes you can can show the whole error to anyone by turning customErrors off, you are right though, you shouldn't when live. This isn't a publically accessible site anyway.

Comment: That's different. One thing is Http errors and another thing the stacktrace and error messages from your website. Http errors like "not found" are public.

Comment: @derloopkat you may be right. Any ideas nonetheless?

Comment: This topic has been asked tens of times and I'm sure you can find answers in previous posts here in stackoverflow. This can be solved by changing settings in your web config and also IIS settings and configuration file at server. You need admin rights on the server.

Comment: Yes you are right, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34190097/can-i-how-do-i-disable-friendly-http-error-messages-in-ms-edge-browser

i'll close my question. Cheers

Comment: just to clarify a little, this is an http error http://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/650x273ximage86.png.pagespeed.gp+jp+jw+pj+js+rj+rp+rw+ri+cp+md.ic.Dg0rRoMZ32.png and this is Asp.Net Error Page http://media-www-asp.azureedge.net/images-legacy/asp.net/images/hosting/11/aspnet_tutorial11_customerrors_cs_figure01.png You can find more details here http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs